# SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient, truststore

I've been trying to debug this error with no luck.

Essentially I'm contacting an external app throught my app. The connection is established fine, the app contacts back my app through a callback URL, then I need to send a final validation to the external app.
This last step is failing because of an SSLHandShajeException.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I've had a look at the possible causes, and created a truststore with the external app cert in it following these steps:

- download the cert chain from the browser
- creating the truststore with

> keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias mycert -file
>   x_my_cert_location_x -keystore truststore

- adding the above trustore in my setenv file
- restart my tomcat instance.

This has not resolved the problem.

I also added to cert to the cacert file, and the same to the connector in the server.xml file as follows:

> ```
> <Connector port="${catalina.port.https}" server="Apache" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
>            SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
>            clientAuth="false"
>            connectionTimeout="20000"
>            compression="on"
>            compressionMinSize="200"
>            compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/xml"
>            enableLookups="false"
>            URIEncoding="UTF-8"
>            keystoreFile="my_store_location" keystorePass="myPwd"/>
> ```

Debugging in the SSL, I can see:

```
> %% Invalidated: [Session-15, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
> http-nio-8080-exec-9, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, description =
> certificate_unknown http-nio-8080-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length
> = 2 [Raw write]: length = 7 0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 2E ....... http-nio-8080-exec-9, called closeSocket() http-nio-8080-exec-9,
> handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target
```

Which makes no real sense to me. My app is on java 1.8.242. Any advice on this please?

Comment: Did you add the cert to:  ./jdk1.8.0_24/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Comment: You need to define the truststore when configuring the Connector. You don't have any assurance that Tomcat uses default SSLContexts that read the system properties.

Comment: I added the cert to the cacerts, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Also, I did the same with the Connector. I will update the question with those info

Comment: I am sure after doing the keytool, it has installed sucessfully

Comment: Correct, after using keytool I got a message saying "Certificate added to file". After that I restarted Tomcat

Comment: Check this out as it might be helpful: https://dzone.com/articles/install-java-cryptography-extension-jce-unlimited

Comment: I did insert the unlimited policies files but with no effect on the result

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you are missing the certificate of the site you are trying to reach. So..

- Start your java/tomcat with `-Djavax.net.debug=ALL`.  In the logs you should see lines like these (I stripped out the timestamp etc.):

  ```
   trustStore is: {your-cacerts-file} trustStore
   type is: pkcs12
   trustStore provider is: the last modified time is: Tue Feb 02 18:29:33 GMT 2021 
   Reload the trust store
   Reload trust
   Reloaded {x} trust certs adding as trusted certificates
   ( {then you get a big dump of all {x} certs.}
  ```

  That way you know for sure if your cacerts is really being read or not.
- If your file is really being read by Tomcat then write your own small Java program that uses your cacerts file (use -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore={path-to-my-file}) and the same debug parameter used above.  You should see it read in the certificate you added.  Then debug from there and maybe repost this smaller case.  That isn't the total answer but at least you will have isolated the problem to some degree.